# .net core / standard string.ToLower() has no culture parameter

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard

In .net fx i can do

```
myString.ToLower(frenchCulture);
```

But when looking at .net core or .net standard there is no more a culture parameter that can be passed. There is only `string.ToLower()` and `string.ToLowerInvariant()`

Should the culture just be ommitted ? But shouldn't then there be issues when the culture of the string is not the current culture?

Any hints what the reason behind this is?

When I have the idea of a invariant culture I can use `ToLowerInvariant()`.

But what about use cases where i have to use `string.ToLower()` in a culture that is not the current culture?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like the capability is there, just in a more roundabout way. Instead of:

```
string output = input.ToLower(culture);
```

use

```
string output = culture.TextInfo.ToLower(input);
```

Also note that the overload has been added in netstandard2.0. The [implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/a125a6e786f09045a28a7d3e4a2c612602f9d220/src/mscorlib/src/System/String.Manipulation.cs#L1664) is basically the code above.